# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}$ by contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, inverse-laplace

I've been trying to prove the result $$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}\}(t)=\frac{1}{18}
(\sin(3t)-3t\cos(3t))$$

by a contour integral. So $$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}\}(t) = \end{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}{\frac{3e^{st}}{(s^2+9)^2}}\, ds $$

(and with poles at $\pm3i$, using a Bromwich contour)

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}\}(t)=\sum{\mathrm{Res}{\left(\frac{3e^{st}}{(s^2+9)^2}\right)}}$$

So with $(s^2+9)^2=(s+3i)^2(s-3i)^2$

$$\begin{align} 
&=3\lim_{s\to3i}\frac{d}{ds}{\left((s-3i)^2 \frac{e^{st}}{(s+3i)^2(s-3i)^2}\right)}+3\lim_{s\to-3i}\frac{d}{ds}{\left((s+3i)^2 \frac{e^{st}}{(s+3i)^2(s-3i)^2}\right)}
\\&=3\lim_{s\to3i}{\left(\frac{te^{st}(s+3i)^2-2e^{st}(s+3i)}{(s+3i)^4}\right)}+3\lim_{s\to-3i}{\left(\frac{te^{st}(s-3i)^2-2e^{st}(s-3i)}{(s-3i)^4}\right)}
\\&=3\lim_{s\to3i}{\left(\frac{e^{st}(t(s+3i)-2)}{(s+3i)^3}\right)}+3\lim_{s\to-3i}{\left(\frac{e^{st}(t(s-3i)-2)}{(s-3i)^3}\right)}
\\&=3\left(\frac{e^{3it}(6it-2)}{-216i}\right)+3\left(\frac{e^{-3it}(-6it-2)}{216i}\right)
\\&=3\left(\frac{-6te^{3it}-2ie^{3it}}{216}\right)-3\left(\frac{6te^{-3it}-2ie^{-3it}}{216}\right)
\\&=3\left(\frac{-6t(e^{3it}+e^{-3it})-2i(e^{3it}-e^{-3it})}{216}\right)
\\&=3\left(\frac{-12t\cos(3t)+4\sin(3t)}{216}\right)
\\&=3\left(\frac{1}{54}(\sin(3t))-\frac{1}{18}(t\cos(3t))\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{18}\left(\sin(3t)-3t\cos(3t)\right)
\end{align}$$

EDIT : Accounted for the 3 in the numerator (and corrected the final line). Proof is all good now.

Comment: You're supposed to get the inverse LT of a function with an overall factor of $3$, which you've forgotten. Your other mistake is accidentally dropping a factor of $t$ in the cosine's coefficient; I'll leave you to re-read your calculation to see where. I advise you with trigonometry-based problems like this to do two calculations at once with $\pm$ viz.$$\sum_\pm\lim_{s\to\pm ai}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{e^{st}}{(s\pm ai)^2}=\frac{\sin at-at\cos at}{2a^3}$$with $a=3$.

Comment: Thank you :) the cosine coefficient was me being careless writing it up in LaTeX but I did forget the 3 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about the 3 in the numerator (thanks @J.G.) and also in the final line I lost a $t$ coefficient on cosine.